# Dents on a car surfaces?

Tags: modeling, add-on

Does anyone know if there is an addon to draw dents on the surfaces?

I would like to make dents in the body of a car using procedural tools, done with "modeling" the surface.

[image]

thanks

Comment: there are no add-ons specifically for dents; although there are add-ons for _decals_ which serve a similar, more general purpose.  You can find those with a google search.  However, this stuff is usually done by creating procedural materials.  There are many good tutorials on that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you wanting to modify the geometry or just bump map a surface material?

Comment: modify the geometry

Comment: Better to insert some reference image to be sure we all speaks about the same ... Something can be done with geometry nodes or modifiers if you premade some system, but I don't know about any addon as well. BTW how do you expect to "draw" a dent?

Comment: http://sindirepamt.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/231748292013421.jpg

Comment: Sorry I started to create some example, but had no time to finish ... as mentioned there is not an addon for that (from what I know), but seems like move a few vertices manually and use texture scratches and a bit of details by Normal map texture would be all you need ... this is not like a bullet hole you could place anywhere :)